# Angular SPA returns 404 on Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: angular, apache, single-page-application

I have a Single Page Application in Angular 8. I deployed my website to the Apache server. As this is the single page application, so it will give a 404 error when refreshing the site, so I put the "*ErrorDocument 404 /index.html* " line inside the .htaccess file. so this issue has been resolved.

But now the problem is when I try to analyze the site with "*https://www.fakedomain.com/about-us*", then it gives an error like this,

**Lighthouse returned an error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 404)Dismiss**

Also, another issue is when input "*https://www.fakedomain.com/about-us*" into the URL field it will get 404 error, in this site for Google Web Cache, https://cachedview.com/

So I'm getting these errors on my analytics, but in a browser, content loads perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You run the following build command to build the application wrote:

```
ng build --base-href=/ --prod
```

To deploy, we just need to copy the code that was generated at director dist /  into the deploy folder of Apache HTTPD server with config to rewrite .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond% {DOCUMENT_ROOT}% {REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond% {DOCUMENT_ROOT}% {REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Remember to change app-name according to your app name. After restart Apache.

```
service httpd restart
```

Goodluck!