# Angular windows.open 404 error, works on local but not on webserver

Tags: javascript, angular

I got an Angular app that calls a window.open that works for with ng serve with http://localhost:4200/newWindow

I can copy and paste this on my ng serve and chrome. it works locally

When the code is deployed to a webserver I get "status":404 "error":"Not Found"

```
window.open('https://myWebserver.com/newWindow', "_blank");
window.open('/newWindow', "_blank");
```

Not sure how I can debug or step into the code on the web server.

When I copy and paste the url on chrome ,https://myWebserver.com/newWindow

I get the 404 error but on my local with http://localhost:4200/newWindow, this works.

I tried using the '#' in the url with the following

https://myWebserver.com/#/newWindow

but no luck

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why `window.open()` doesn't work in your case, but couldn't you just use the routing as it's intended by Angular?

Comment: What backend stack are you using? Is your angular app perhaps a PWA? When you're on `/NewWindow`, do you get the page after **ctrl+F5**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve index.html in case of 404 in that domain, this depend on what web-server you're using. Firebase deployments have an option for SPA. while Apache and Nginx requires you to edit the configurations

See [Angular SPA returns 404 on Google PageSpeed Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384363/angular-spa-returns-404-on-google-pagespeed-insights) for Apache

The reason it works in development that `ng serve` is already handling this

Answer (score -1):

Angular uses [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) to update the URLs.

The History API is designed to let a developer say: *I have modified the document using JavaScript, it is now in the same state as you would get if you just loaded the HTML document from this URL*.

Unfortunately, Angular doesn't do much to make that statement true outside of the development server (as you've observed).

The usual ways to solve this problem are with [Server-Side Rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal) or with [Static Site Generation](https://github.com/scullyio/scully).

A hacky approach is to deliver the same HTML document for all unknown URLs and depend on client-side code to load all the page content for it. (This is bad food for search engines, breaks your ability use to `Status 404` when a URL really isn't found, and for situations where the JS [fails to load or run for any reason](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).) How you go about that depends on your server, [this page has an example for Apache HTTP](https://dev.to/timetc/angular-with-clean-urls-using-apaches-modrewrite-2bjb).